# T-SQL in SQL Server - bug or feature?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following select:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pl 
FROM [dbo].[VendorPriceList] h
WHERE PartNumber IN (SELECT DISTINCT PartNumber 
                     FROM [dbo].InvoiceData 
                     WHERE amount > 10 
                       AND invoiceDate > DATEADD(yyyy, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

                     UNION

                     SELECT DISTINCT PartNumber 
                     FROM [dbo].VendorDeals)
```

The issue here is that the table `[dbo].VendorDeals` has NO column `PartNumber`, however no error is detected and the query works with the first part of the union.

Even more, IntelliSense also allows and recognize `PartNumber`. This fails only when inside a complex statement.

It is pretty obvious that if you qualify column names, the mistake will be evident.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a **minimal reproducible example**. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: No this isn't a bug, it's due to your lack of qualifying your columns.

Comment: [No, this is not a bug in T-SQL](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2019/04/23/no-this-is-not-a-bug-in-t-sql/)

Comment: `DISTINCT` and `UNION` (as opposed to `UNION ALL`) are logically pointless in that subquery, any case `UNION` implies `DISTINCT`

Comment: @marc_s the missing  just a typo from the editor.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky The question is brief and very reproductible; no data is required nor the table definition, if you take the time to read the question.

Comment: It's a hyperlink, @fcm, you're meant to read the article linked of the same name, which tells you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 5):

[This isn't a bug in SQL Server/the T-SQL dialect](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2019/04/23/no-this-is-not-a-bug-in-t-sql/) parsing, no, this is working *exactly* as intended. The problem, or bug, is in *your* T-SQL; specifically because you haven't qualified your columns. As I don't have the definition of your table, I'm going to provide sample DDL first:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1 (MyColumn varchar(10), OtherColumn int);
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table2 (YourColumn varchar(10) OtherColumn int);
```

And then an example that is similar to your query:

```sql
SELECT MyColumn
FROM dbo.Table1
WHERE MyColumn IN (SELECT MyColumn FROM dbo.Table2);
```

This, firstly, will parse; it is a valid query. Secondly, provided that `dbo.Table2` contains *at least* one row, then **every** row from table `dbo.Table1` will be returned where `MyColumn` has a non-`NULL` value. Why? Well, let's qualify the column with table's name as SQL Server would parse them:

```sql
SELECT Table1.MyColumn
FROM dbo.Table1
WHERE Table1.MyColumn IN (SELECT Table1.MyColumn FROM dbo.Table2);
```

Notice that the column *inside* the `IN` is also referencing `Table1`, **not** `Table2`. By default if a column has it's alias omitted in a subquery it will be *assumed* to be referencing the table(s) defined in that subquery. *If*, however, none of the tables in the sub query have a column by that name, then it will be assumed to reference a table where that column *does* exist; in this case `Table1`.

Let's, instead, take a different example, using the other column in the tables:

```sql
SELECT OtherColumn
FROM dbo.Table1
WHERE OtherColumn IN (SELECT OtherColumn FROM dbo.Table2);
```

This would be parsed as the following:

```sql
SELECT Table1.OtherColumn
FROM dbo.Table1
WHERE Table1.OtherColumn IN (SELECT Table2.OtherColumn FROM dbo.Table2);
```

This is because `OtherColumn` exists in *both* tables. As, in the subquery, `OtherColumn` isn't qualified it is *assumed* the column wanted is the one in the table defined in the same scope, `Table2`.

So what is the solution? Alias and qualify your columns:

```sql
SELECT T1.MyColumn
FROM dbo.Table1 T1
WHERE T1.MyColumn IN (SELECT T2.MyColumn FROM dbo.Table2 T2);
```

This will, unsurprisingly, error as `Table2` has no column `MyColumn`.

Personally, I suggest that unless you have only *one* table being referenced in a query, you alias and qualify *all* your columns. This not only ensures that the wrong column can't be referenced (such as in a subquery) but also means that other readers know exactly what columns are being referenced. It also stops failures in the future. I have honestly lost count how many times over years I have had a process fall over due to the "ambiguous column" error, due to a table's definition being changed and a query referencing the table wasn't properly qualified by the developer...