# How can I decrease the execution cost of my CASE expressions?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have this CASE expression in my query:

```
    CASE el.faunaType
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Examine "' + ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 cellComplex FROM cellList WHERE TRY_CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), cellID) = TRY_CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), faunaSource)), '') + '"'
        WHEN 9 THEN 'Investigate "' + (SELECT TOP 1 sourceText FROM diseaseSources WHERE TRY_CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), sourceID) = TRY_CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), faunaSource)) + '"'
        WHEN 15 THEN 'Infection detected "' + (SELECT TOP 1 sourceText FROM diseaseSources WHERE TRY_CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), sourceID) = TRY_CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), faunaSource)) + '"'
        WHEN 23 THEN 'Forward on "' + (SELECT TOP 1 cellComplex FROM cellList WHERE TRY_CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), cellID) = TRY_CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), faunaSource)) + '"'
        WHEN 45 THEN 'Traced cell "' + ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 cellComplex FROM cellList WHERE TRY_CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), cellID) = TRY_CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), faunaSource)), '') + '"'
        WHEN 77 THEN 'Sampled on "' + (SELECT TOP 1 cellComplex FROM cellList WHERE TRY_CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), cellID) = TRY_CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), faunaSource)) + '"<br />[' + faunaMessage + ']'
    END As FaunaName
```

This block is causing a huge performance hit.  When I view the Execution Plan, I see 20% costs on both `diseaseSources` and `cellList`.

It is doing a Clustered Index Scan.

I have the ID(cellID and sourceID) of both of those tables as Primary Keys.

Is there a way to decrease the performance cost of this CASE statement?

Comment: So you're querying a bunch of tables which is always going to be somewhat costly. The other problem is you're calling `try_convert` on all your table columns, which makes the query unable to use indexes (it doesn't know that the converted version of your column indexes the same as the un-altered column). If it were me, I'd assign all those values to variables first, and try to get the values without converting the column. Also, you're hitting the same table (`cellList`) 4 times. Get all those values in a single pass.

Comment: Also, it would be helpful to see what surrounds that case statement, because you may be querying it in a way that isn't optimal. I'd suggest expanding your code snippet so we can see the whole query; not just the case statement.

Comment: A `TOP (1)` without an `ORDER BY` is also the sign of a flaw; the value you get back is going to be completely arbitrary and *could* be different each time you run the query.

Comment: *"It is doing a Clustered Index Scan."* Of course it is. As @Xedni mentioned, you are *converting* the column in your `WHERE` so the queries aren't SARGable. Why are you converting them to start with? Considering these are related ID values then surely they have key constraints on them and so they *must* be the same datatype, no?

Comment: Also you don't qualify the columns in your subqueries; I *assume* that means that all the columns are meant to be referencing the table(s) define in the subquery? For example (without the "noise") you mean `SELECT cL.cellComplex FROM dbo.cellList cL WHERE cL.cellID = cL.faunaSource`? If you don't then you *really* should get into the habit of aliasing your objects and qualifying your columns. Otherwise you're going to encounter a bug in ***your code***, *[not T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67694095/2029983)*.

Comment: I have the feeling that if you would post your full query, as you should because we're just guessing now, that we would be blown away by a query whose length does not end and has complex constructs in every nook and cranny. In any case, you launch a full query per row selected in the outer query now... that is probably not what you want to do. Probably you should be having a join to those tables in the outer query.

Comment: Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis i didn't close it, but the idea is that if OP doesnt have enough details it's hard to help him and question can be closed (and then reopened when more information is supplied). I don't know how well this works in practice but cest la vie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit of a guess at your table structures to generate HTML, but you'd be better off joining once and then changing the way you handle the SQL. In your example you'd be doing a unique select statement for each case, while a join does the matching once and handles the display after.

```
DECLARE @FT TABLE(faunaType NVARCHAR(100),faunaSource NVARCHAR(50),faunaMessage NVARCHAR(100))
DECLARE @CL TABLE(cellID NVARCHAR(50),cellComplex NVARCHAR(100))
DECLARE @DS TABLE(sourceID NVARCHAR(50),sourceText NVARCHAR(100))

SELECT *,
    CASE el.faunaType
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Examine "' + ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 cellComplex FROM @CL WHERE TRY_CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), cellID) = TRY_CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), faunaSource)), '') + '"'
        WHEN 9 THEN 'Investigate "' + (SELECT TOP 1 sourceText FROM @DS WHERE TRY_CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), sourceID) = TRY_CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), faunaSource)) + '"'
        WHEN 15 THEN 'Infection detected "' + (SELECT TOP 1 sourceText FROM @DS WHERE TRY_CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), sourceID) = TRY_CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), faunaSource)) + '"'
        WHEN 23 THEN 'Forward on "' + (SELECT TOP 1 cellComplex FROM @CL WHERE TRY_CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), cellID) = TRY_CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), faunaSource)) + '"'
        WHEN 45 THEN 'Traced cell "' + ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 cellComplex FROM @CL WHERE TRY_CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), cellID) = TRY_CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), faunaSource)), '') + '"'
        WHEN 77 THEN 'Sampled on "' + (SELECT TOP 1 cellComplex FROM @CL WHERE TRY_CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), cellID) = TRY_CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), faunaSource)) + '"<br />[' + faunaMessage + ']'
    END As FaunaName
FROM @FT el

SELECT *,
    CASE el.faunaType
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Examine "' + ISNULL(cellComplex, '') + '"'
        WHEN 9 THEN 'Investigate "' + ISNULL(sourceText, '') + '"'
        WHEN 15 THEN 'Infection detected "' + ISNULL(sourceText, '') + '"'
        WHEN 23 THEN 'Forward on "' + ISNULL(cellComplex, '') + '"'
        WHEN 45 THEN 'Traced cell "' + ISNULL(cellComplex, '') + '"'
        WHEN 77 THEN 'Sampled on "' + ISNULL(cellComplex, '') + '"<br />[' + faunaMessage + ']'
    END As FaunaName
FROM @FT el 
LEFT JOIN @DS ds ON ds.sourceID=el.faunaSource
LEFT JOIN @CL cl ON cl.cellID=el.faunaSource
```